# Square API and ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, square-connect

I am trying to take an existing ColdFusion website that currently uses Authorize to process cards. I would like to switch over the payment gateway and use Square. Does anyone have any sample ColdFusion code on how to use the Square API as a payment gateway?

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a gist another developer has used](https://gist.github.com/tristansokol/ac2b2850153e58b7ca8a5c5af407458c)

```
<cfset IDKey = CreateUUID()>
<cfset request.params.card_nonce = form.nonce>
<cfset request.params.amount_money.amount = 100>
<cfset request.params.amount_money.currency = 'USD'>
<cfset request.params.idempotency_key = IDKey>
<cfset jsonString = serializejson(request.params)>
<cfset requestPath = "https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/<replace_locationid>/transactions">
<cfhttp url="#requestPath#" method="post" result="response">
    <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Accept" value="application/json">
    <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
    <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Authorization" value="Bearer <replace_access_token>">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" name="params" value="#jsonString#">
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Thanks But what are the parameters that were in form.nonce?

Comment: Check out this document, you need to use a client side javascript form to generate the card nonce. https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/paymentform-overview

Comment: Why couldnt I use something like this?

Comment: <cfset v_string="applicationId:#v_appid#,sq-card-number:#v_cardnumber#,sq-cvv:#v_cvv#,sq-expiration-date:#v_expirationDate#,sq-postal-code:#v_postalCode#">
<cfset request.params.card_nonce = "#v_string#">

Comment: is your code very different? I'd love to improve my snippet since I don't have any cold fusion experience myself.

Comment: It is not much different. the only thing I added is code above to get the location id

Comment: <cfset jsonString = serializejson(request.params)>
<cfset requestPath = "https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations">
<cfhttp url="#requestPath#" method="get" result="response">
    <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Accept" value="application/json">
    <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
    <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Authorization" value="Bearer myid">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" name="params" value="#jsonString#">
</cfhttp>

<cfset v_result = deserializeJSON(response.FileContent)>
<cfset v_locationid = "#v_result.locations[1].id#">

Comment: At bit off topic. Square does money in cents. So the 100 in the code above is actually US$1.00

Comment: David Adress, would you care to share your implementation efforts?

Comment: FYI: The "transactions" API is now deprecated (not sure when) and has been split into separate "payments" & "refunds" endpoints.