# Can Square work in a CF ecommerce site?

Tags: coldfusion, square-connect

Can Square work in a CF ecommerce site? From our developer: This will be a bit technical but the way their API system works is they encapsulate the credit card data directly from a form entry with their css and js files. That system generates a "nonce" that then gets processed through the actual API REST call. That works fine in many typical sites. But we would need to make that REST call without an actual form/client step. CF has an internal  HTML processing engine, but it's not going to run the javascript internally to do the encapsulation step.  We need to make a straight REST call with a way to generate the "nonce" with our ColdFusion engine or at least a JAVA call.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, so it's going to get closed.. the short answer though is 'yes'.  See this previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836797/square-api-and-coldfusion

Comment: I'd recommend your developer asking the questions next time. Please do check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836797/square-api-and-coldfusion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Square API and ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836797/square-api-and-coldfusion)